# Adding machines to the domain in a Read Only Domain Controller (RODC) site

Tags: windows, ldap

I have a site with terrible physical security and a terrible network connection. So I need a domain controller onsite (for when the network connection goes down) but it also needs to be a RODC for security reasons.

The machines onsite in this office have access to other read write domain controllers in other parts of the network. There's no firewall blocking them. I just don't want someone to be able to plug a keyboard / mouse into our domain controller on site and change stuff.

When adding new machines to the domain on this site, do I need to follow the process of creating a computer object in AD and then doing an offline domain join (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/dd392267(v=ws.10))? Or can I somehow force machines that are currently not part of the domain to go to a RWDC (configured in another AD site) to get added to the domain the normal way?

Comment: Provided your clients can access the domain controllers at the main site, I believe it should just all work as normal - the clients should be smart enough to locate a RWDC to use for the domain join.  Problems may occur if some of the clients aren't running Windows (as per the first link in Dion's answer) or don't have network access to the main site (as per the second link in Dion's answer).

Answer (score 0):

Sadly it seems you will have to create a computer account and then replicate it through your AD domain like what you already found:

https://docs.centrify.com/en/css/2017.3-html/index.html#page/Planning,_preparation,_and_deployment/How_to_join_a_domain_with_a_read-only_domain_con.5.html

There is this script I found that claims it  can do it as well:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Domain-Join-through-an-9a010eb5

Most scripts I find on the TechNet Gallery work like a champ. However since I don't have a RODC I can't test sadly. There might be a way to redirect it to another DC that belongs to another site but if you have strict security compliance that could be a bad thing to do.

**Edit**

If you were going to try to point it to a different DC I think it would be as simple as configuring the clients DNS to point to a RWDC. Then either through DHCP or manual configuration reset the IP settings especially DNS to the RODC. But again if you have compliance you have to meet this could be frowned upon.